# How can I easily analyze an Oracle package's execution for performance issues?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a pl/sql package in an 11g R2 DB that has a fair number of related procedures & functions. I execute a top level function and it does a whole lot of stuff. It is currently processing < 10 rows per second. I would like to improve the performance, but I am not sure which of the routines to focus on.

This seems like a good job for Oracle's "PL/SQL hierarchical profiler (DBMS_HPROF)" Being the lazy person that I am I was hoping that either SQLDeveloper v3.2.20.09 or Enterprise Manager would be able do what I want with a point & click interface. I cannot find this.

Is there an "easy" way to analyze the actual PL/SQL code in a procedure/package?

I have optimized the queries in the package using the "Top Activity" section of Enterprise Manager, looking at all of the queries that were taking a long time. Now all I have is a single "Execute PL/SQL" showing up, and I need to break that down into at least the procedures & functions that are called, and what percentage of the time they are taking.

Comment: Go read this - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_profil.htm

Comment: Thanks, one problem I have with Oracle, is that when I want to know what time it is, they seem to want to tell me how to build a watch. I suspect that if I read that and/or this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_profiler.htm#ADFNS02302 I can probably figure out how to do what I need to do, and it will be very enlightening, and I will be a better person/programmer for the effort. But what I want to do is just find out which bloody procedures take the most time.

Comment: DBMS_PROFILER does that for you.  It is not difficult to use.  It will show you timing for each line of code in a nice HTML report.

Answer (score 4):

The PL/SQL Hierarchical Profiler, documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_profiler.htm#ADFNS023), is actually very easy to run, assuming that you have the necessary privileges.

Basically you just need to run a PL/SQL block like this:

```
begin
   dbms_hprof.start_profiling('PLSHPROF_DIR', 'test.trc');
   your_top_level_procedure;
   dbms_hprof.stop_profiling;
end;
```

The `plshprof` utility will generate HTML reports from the raw profiler output file (`test.trc` in the example above).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to get through the documentation, find all the errors that Oracle will undoubtedly spew, and perhaps it will provide something useful. What I was hoping for was something in SQLDeveloper, or Oracle Enterprise Manager that might make it simpler.

Comment: It wasn't too bad, I only had to enable the packages, grant permissions, create tables, and generally muck about for 20 minutes. Once I ran it, and plshprof, I have a lovely set of html files with no decent docs easily found. I know this sounds like I'm just griping, but jeez couldn't Oracle put together something easy to use and then easy to understand? Does anyone know where I can find decent docs on the output from plshprof?

Comment: have you proceed output with [`DBMS_HPROF.analyze`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm#CHDEEABH)? all the available reports are described in the docs