# SUM is slower than loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am currently trying to optimize a view, that wasn't written by me. It is really complex, with a lot views using function that use views and so on.
So, playing around with what I can optimize I have something  I can't really understand:
I have this function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION at_get_tourenrechnungssumme_br (in_rechnr IN rechnungen.rechnr%TYPE)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
      CURSOR c1 (
         int_rechnr   IN rechnungen.rechnr%TYPE)
      IS
         SELECT (ROUND (
                     verrechnung.get_betrag (bt.buchid, bt.betrag_euro)*(1+b.mwst/100),
                   2))
                   betrag
           FROM buchungen_touren bt, v_buchkz b
          WHERE     bt.rechnr = int_rechnr
                AND bt.storniert_jn = 0
                AND bt.buchid = b.ID;
      int_return   NUMBER (11, 2) := 0;
   BEGIN
      FOR c1_rec IN c1 (in_rechnr)
      LOOP
         int_return := (int_return + c1_rec.betrag);
      END LOOP;

      RETURN NVL (int_return, 0);
   END at_get_tourenrechnungssumme_br;
```

I just thought: loops are bad, you can do the same with sum:

```
create or replace FUNCTION at_get_tourenrechnungssumme_br (in_rechnr IN rechnungen.rechnr%TYPE)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
      int_return   NUMBER (11, 2) := 0;
   BEGIN
      SELECT sum(ROUND (
                     verrechnung.get_betrag (bt.buchid, bt.betrag_euro)*(1+b.mwst/100),
                   2))
                   betrag
           into int_return        
           FROM buchungen_touren bt, v_buchkz b
          WHERE     bt.rechnr = in_rechnr
                AND bt.storniert_jn = 0
                AND bt.buchid = b.ID;

      RETURN NVL (int_return, 0);
   END at_get_tourenrechnungssumme_br;
```

The strange thing is, that it good actually slower, by the factor of ~2. Does `sum` just don't like functions?
Can someone explain this?

Edit:
This is more of an theoretical question. The obvious solution is: avoid using functions(which I mostly do, when I optimize views, someone else wrote), which I did, but I think, the question is still interesting.

Comment: How you find the `sum` is slower than `loop`. do you use any `DBMS_PROFILER`. posting the result will be helpful to find solution

Comment: Haven't used DBMS_Profiler yet. I made a loop, which calls the function in the context I need it(over 8000 times) first code takes 4-6 seconds, second takes 11-14.

Comment: @user2179887 . . . The two snippets of code are not equivalent.  The first is calling the `verrechnung.get_betrag()` function twice for each row; the second is only calling it once.  Use the same expression in both, and I'm guessing you'll find that the `sum()` is faster.

Comment: That was actually another optimization. You don't have to call `verrechnung.get_betrag()` twice, that is bad math.
I change it in the question, so people don't get confused.

Comment: What does `get_betrag` do? If it executes any kind of SQL query, you still end up processing data sequentially, only the cursor does it one record at a time while the SQL statement tries to execute run all queries corresponding to the external rows at once. It may be that IO contention causes the second query to run slower

Comment: My solution was, that I just don't use `get_betrag` or `at_get_tourenrechnungssumme_br`, but put the logic in another subselect. Now, it works fine. But I am still curious, what caused the difference. Can anyone walk me through how to analyze that?

Comment: and yes, `get_betrag`, just executes an SQL-Query.

Comment: @user2179887: you can also try the PL/SQL hierarchical profiler which will break down the elapsed time of the main function into its components, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771192/how-can-i-easily-analyze-an-oracle-packages-execution-for-performance-issues/19771515#19771515)

Answer (score 1):

The difference in run time is down to PL/SQL / SQL context switching.  When embedding a PL/SQL function into a SQL statement Oracle needs to switch back and forth between the two engines.  Consider this very simplistic test which nevertheless illustrates the difference.

**Create a Simple Function**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (a IN number, b in NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
  2  AS
  3  
  4  BEGIN
  5          return a+b;
  6  END;
  7  /

Function created.
```

**Simple Query performing addition and aggregation in pure SQL**

```
  1  WITH
  2  row_gen
  3  AS (
  4 SELECT LEVEL as a, level as b
  5 FROM DUAL
  6 CONNECT BY LEVEL < 1000000
  7 )
  8  SELECT SUM(a+b)
  9* FROM row_gen
SQL> /

  SUM(A+B)
----------
1.0000E+12

Elapsed: 00:00:00.36
```

**Simple Query Performing Aggregation with PL/SQL function call**

```
  1  WITH
  2  row_gen
  3  AS (
  4 SELECT LEVEL as a, level as b
  5 FROM DUAL
  6 CONNECT BY LEVEL < 1000000
  7 )
  8  SELECT SUM(test(b,b))
  9* FROM row_gen
SQL> /

SUM(TEST(B,B))
--------------
    1.0000E+12

Elapsed: 00:00:00.87
```

So the pure SQL example takes 0.36 of a second whilst the one with the SQL / PLSQL context switch takes slightly more than twice the time at 0.87 seconds.

Comment: both variants of the function do a PL/SQL / SQL switching

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  I disagree with @a.j.tawleed - the "test" function is not called so there is no pl/sql context switch in the second example.  I also find the style of the answer to be very good.

Comment: In the question, both examples have a PL/SQL / SQL-switch

Answer (score 0):

In the SUM case, you might be waiting for memory or disk. The optimizer might be materializing the results of your function calls so it can sum them after they're pre-calculated. In the PL/SQL loop, you're explicitly discarding previously read rows, reducing allocation costs, and a FIRST_ROWS optimization might also mean that you can get started with the math before the disk is finished reading all the data.

This is speculation, and profiling is the only way to know for sure.